# Java/XML - Change TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Can someone explain me why this code doesn't work? I want to change the text of the textview with Java code but nothing changes.

```
package com.example.gethtml;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;    

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GetCode getCode = new GetCode();
    Affiche affiche = new Affiche();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            getCode.getCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: posted same code multiple time 
edit your code and update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code to change the `textview`'s text through java code should contain at least one `TextView` object to start with. I can not see that in your code. But I am writing below a sample code for that.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);
txtView.setText("This is changed text");
```

Your `activity_main.xml` should contain `TextView` defined with id you are referring. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ho I'm sorry i put the wrong code (kill me). But your code works thanks