# java variable in XML android

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to know how to be able to use variables in XML from my java file. The variables are Doubles, with most being null, so I believe I would have to convert them to Strings and set those equal to null as "unknown", but how would I get those Strings to be of use in my strings.xml file?
This is my first question, as I am new to coding apps, but I have learned Java before, and XML has been easy so far.

Edit: What I am trying to do is design a type of calculator by asking for the variables and solving for the others in the java code, and then displaying them somehow to the user. Is there any (other) way that I can display variables after some calculations?

Comment: You cannot use Java variables in your XML file.

Comment: You can't change resource files at runtime so this would never work. If you explain *why* you think you need to do this then maybe we can help with a better way. But this won't work

Comment: Well, in the end, since in the end I want to display it on the screen, so I thought I would convert Double x to String x, move the String to strings.xml as a <string>, then use @string/var reference in a textBox on a layout XML file.

Comment: But, as I said, you can't do that. `resource` files can't be changed at runtime.

Comment: I would ask them on main.xml, put their response in a Double variable, do what I said I did in my previous comment when they clicked the "solve" button, and finally display the results in results.xml. I don't see what's wrong with that, and I am sorry if that was not understood at first.

Comment: Once the layout xml is inflated, it turns into Java Objects.  Once that happens, you can just modify your TextView (or whatever you want to use for display of the numbers) in your Java code.  You're not "displaying the results in results.xml", you're displaying them in the Objects that were the result of results.xml being inflated.

Comment: XML is a read-only file.

Comment: I got it, what I was trying to do is what Daniel said about editing after inflation. I looked up how to do it, and now I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might understand, but I'll have to explain it anyway so that you tell me if I'm wrong. So you want a person to put in the numbers and choose the operation, then do that operation using java. Then you want java to send the final answer to the xml file so it displays the answer on the screen.

Here's how I would do that:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);
txtView.setText("This is changed text");
```

Comment: try checking out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252962/java-xml-change-textview